# Open two tcp connection using TcpListener class on both side

Tags: c#, tcp

I want to open tcp connection between two machine. 
I want to use the class TcpListener on the client side and on the server side and by this to have the option to make the two side 'talk' with the other by sending and receiving byte[].

That mean that each side is a server and a client.

I using the code from msdn to do it. 
But on this code the server start and wait till the client will connect to him.

If i doing so on the both sides i will fail. 
Is there any other way ?

The code:

```
public static void Main()
{  
   TcpListener server=null;   
   try
   {
  // Set the TcpListener on port 13000.
  Int32 port = 13000;
  IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");

  // TcpListener server = new TcpListener(port);
  server = new TcpListener(localAddr, port);

  // Start listening for client requests.
  server.Start();

  // Buffer for reading data
  Byte[] bytes = new Byte[256];
  String data = null;

  // Enter the listening loop.
  while(true) 
  {
    Console.Write("Waiting for a connection... ");

    // Perform a blocking call to accept requests.
    // You could also user server.AcceptSocket() here.
    TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();            
    Console.WriteLine("Connected!");

    data = null;

    // Get a stream object for reading and writing
    NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

    int i;

    // Loop to receive all the data sent by the client.
    while((i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length))!=0) 
    {   
      // Translate data bytes to a ASCII string.
      data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
      Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", data);

      // Process the data sent by the client.
      data = data.ToUpper();

      byte[] msg = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

      // Send back a response.
      stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
      Console.WriteLine("Sent: {0}", data);            
    }

    // Shutdown and end connection
    client.Close();
  }
}
catch(SocketException e)
{
  Console.WriteLine("SocketException: {0}", e);
}
finally
{
   // Stop listening for new clients.
   server.Stop();
}


Console.WriteLine("\nHit enter to continue...");
Console.Read();
 }
```

Comment: You need a basic sockets tutorial. One socket listens, the other connects, then both can talk in both directions.

Comment: I know that there are TcpListener and TcpClient that i can use. On the TcpClient i can't wait to get byte[] from the server as far as i know

Comment: If i wrong please help me .. 10x

Comment: TcpClient has a `Receive` method same as the server.

Comment: but how can wait the data that will send by the server ? i fail when i try

Comment: @Yanshof: I am not sure if I understood your question correctly but to let two applications talk to each other you DO NOT need to instantiate a `TcpListener` class on each side. Just use the `TcpListener` class on one side and use an `TcpClient`class on the *connecting* side (as shown in my example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume there is some missunderstanding...
The [`TcpListener`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener(v=vs.110).aspx) class is used to open a listener. This represents an endpoint to whom a client can connect (like e.g. a WebServer). To actually connect to such an endpoint you need to use an instance of the [`TcpClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

**Following a simple example (written out of my head and NOT TESTED!), also be advised that there is no error handling included and this should just give you a hint where and how to start.**

**Serverside**

```
// Create a local endpoint (all network interfaces at port 80)
// and create a listener that uses that endpoint.
IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 80);
TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(localEndPoint);

// Start the listener.
listener.Start();

// Wait (blocking) until a client connects.
TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();

// Stop the listener (so no one else can connect).
listener.Stop();

// Fetch the underlying network stream which
// allows reading and writing data between us and
// the connected client.
NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream();

// Read data from the stream.
byte[] dataBuffer = new byte[8192];
int receivedBytes = ns.Read(dataBuffer, 0, dataBuffer.Length);

// Translate it back to a text by using UTF-8 encoding.
Console.WriteLine($"I have received {receivedBytes} bytes:");
Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(dataBuffer, 0, receivedBytes));

// Write an answert to the client.
dataBuffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Thank you for your message!");
ns.Write(dataBuffer, 0, dataBuffer.Length);

// Close everything.
ns.Flush();
ns.Close();
client.Close();
```

**Clientside**

```
// Create a remote endpoint (the ip you want to connect to at port 80)
// and create a client that uses that endpoint.
IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("the ip you want to connect to"), 80);
TcpClient client = new TcpClient();

// Try to connect to that endpoint.
client.Connect(remoteEndPoint);

// Fetch the underlying network stream which
// allows reading and writing data between us and
// the connected client.
NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream();

// Write something to the server.
byte[] dataBuffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello, I am here.");
ns.Write(dataBuffer, 0, dataBuffer.Length);

// Read an answer back from the server.
dataBuffer = new byte[8192];
int receivedBytes = ns.Read(dataBuffer, 0, dataBuffer.Length);

// Translate it back to a text by using UTF-8 encoding.
Console.WriteLine($"I have received an answer with {receivedBytes} bytes:");
Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(dataBuffer, 0, receivedBytes));

// Close everything.
ns.Flush();
ns.Close();
client.Close();
```

---

The example above obviously does just send one message and closes the application afterwards. If you need to wait until data has arrived, you can use the `DataAvailable` property of the `NetworkStream` which indicates whether data is available or not. If not, just sleep and try again later.

**Example**

```
bool iWantToReceiveData = true;

while (iWantToReceiveData)
{
    // If no data is available...
    if (!ns.DataAvailable)
    {
        // ...wait some time and try again later.
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        continue;
    }

    // Read an answer back from the server.
    dataBuffer = new byte[8192];
    int receivedBytes = ns.Read(dataBuffer, 0, dataBuffer.Length);

    // Translate it back to a text by using UTF-8 encoding.
    Console.WriteLine($"I have received an answer with {receivedBytes} bytes:");
    Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(dataBuffer, 0, receivedBytes));
}
```

Of course this is some kind of blocking beaviour so you will have to handle that in a separate thread.

I would suggest building an `EnhancedNetworkStream` class which has a thread running in the background that does the cyclic checking for new data and fires an event once new data has arrived.

Comment: Thanks, but on the client side => if i want to make some method that will continue get the buffer from the server side - and make some dialog between the server and the client how to do it ? 

on your way the 'dialog' ends after receiving the buffer from the server

Comment: @Yanshof - use `Async` methods or another thread/task to be able to having an outstanding call to `Receive` that can react when data is available, independent from your code that is calling `Send` methods.